# How can I fix Conductor to properly work with Instant Run on Android

Tags: android

When Conductor demo (or my test app, whatever) is refreshed using InstaRun (simply by running app again: Ctrl-R on OSX, you can add just empty line to the code, InstaRun will refresh your project and restart Activity), Controller is not created - I end up with empty Activity.

It is possibly linked with this issue: https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor/issues/32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creator of the Conductor fixed this issue.